# Getting value of Html textbox when html Button Clicked

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to get html textbox value when click on html button without using "runat" attribute.I need to do it in code behind ,is it possible?

```
<button id="button1" onclick="btnclick">Click Here</button><input type="text" id="txtBox1" name="txtBox12" />
```

and My code Behind is like:

```
protected void btnclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = Request.Form["txtBox12"];
            Response.Write(name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MODIFIED

To access any control in code behind it needs to have runat=server attribute attached to it.

In your case, like you pointed you can transfer the value of input text to asp hidden field and then access

its value on button click in server-side but in this case too you have to place hidden field inside form runat=server tag.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="PassValue(this);";/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
-----------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PassValue(obj) {
            document.getElementById("hf").value = obj.value;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: as I said: To access any control in code behind it needs to have runat=server attribute attached to it.

Comment: thak you I will try it

Comment: This will do the trick for you after placing runat="server"
string myString= txtBox1.Value;